# Can webpack handle require() correctly?

Tags: webpack, require

I understand that Webpack allows users to import and export modules using es6 module syntax, AMD or commonJS. However, when working on a webpack project, a simple require statement is raising errors.

This is in the context of a freshly created "create-react-app" project.

## config.js

```
const packageJson = require('../package.json');

const baseConfig = {
    urls: {
        base: packageJson.homepage,
        engineServer: 'localhost:3001'
    },
    useArrowKeysToCycleViews: false
};

const debugStyleConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    useArrowKeysToCycleViews: true
};

module.exports = { // <-- IMPORTANT
    config: debugStyleConfig
};
```

## index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import './boot'; // <-- IMPORTANT
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

## boot.js

```
// The following line...
import { config } from './config';
// ... raises this error:
// Attempted import error: 'config' is not exported from './config'.

// If the following line is used instead...
// const { config } = require('./config');
// ...a different error is raised:
// TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
```

In trying to understand the issue, I created a second project that makes use of `module.exports` and `require`. However, strangely, the following works perfectly.

## foo.js

```
function foo() {
    return 'fooz';
}

function bar() {
    return 'bar';
}

module.exports = {
    foo, bar
};
```

## App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
const { foo, bar } = require('./foo');

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <h1>{foo()}</h1>
        <h1>{bar()}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Is there a nuance to using `require` and `module.exports` with webpack that is not entirely forthcoming?

Comment: What is the error you got? How can a reader reproduce what you see?

Comment: Just experimenting with the stack overflow editor...it is blocking me from posting my whole post, claiming that some of it should be formatted as code when it is not code.

Comment: That was really odd, the WYSIWYG kept compaining that I needed to format natural language portions of my post as code. Seems to be working ok now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working now. The problem was in the `config.js` file. When I change:

```
const debugStyleConfig = {
    ...baseConfig,
    useArrowKeysToCycleViews: true
};
```

to

```
const debugStyleConfig = {
    useArrowKeysToCycleViews: true
};
```

...the error goes away. I believe this could be the result of the `Object.assign` shorthand / object spread operator being unsupported by nodeJS. But it is a bit of a gotcha that it does this rather than raise a syntax error.